# jaxrs 0.8 plugin - unable to resolve classes

Tags: grails, jax-rs, grails-2.0

I am using following configuration for grails project.

```
STS :- Version: 3.5.0.M2
Grails :- 2.3.8
Groovy compiler :- 2.2
jaxrs 0.8
```

After installing jaxrs 0.8 plugin it is giving error

```
unable to resolve org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.JSONParsingParameterCreationListener &
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.XMLParsingParameterCreationListener
```

Please help me to resolve these error.

Thanks